# Change Offset of array in java

Tags: java, arrays

In C we can change offset of array by following code

```
int arr1a[] = arr+3;
```

This will change the base of array by 3 indexes.

In java we can not do this. So what is the best practice to tackle this in java.

We can use `Arrays.copyOf()`, but this will increase the complexity.

The complexity of `Array.copyOf` is O(n). Internally it uses `System.arraycopy` whose complexity is O(n)

Comment: That's the whole point of Java. You can't mess with address locations using pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to copy the array, just keep an `offset` variable and add it wherever needed:

```
int[] arr = { 1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34 }

// View of array: 5,8,13,21
int offset = 3, len = 4;
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    System.out.println(arr[i + offset]);
```

In `C`, an array doesn't know its own size, so you have to keep track of that yourself, but offsetting is easier.
In `Java`, an array knows its own size, but you have to keep track of any offset needed.
Either way, you have to do some of it yourself, just a different part of it. Such is life.